# Problema ao identificar se alguma palavra de uma lista está presente na minha string no Python

Tags: python, string, algoritmo-de-busca

Eu estou querendo identificar se no meu input há alguma palavra que está em uma lista de palavras que criei. O código roda normal sem apresentar nenhum erro, porém, está errando o resultando sempre.

**Código:**

```
x = input('Insira aqui o email:\n')
x = re.sub('-'," ", x)
x = str(x)
x=x.lower()
x=x.translate(punc_table)
import csv
with open("fornecedores.csv") as f_obj:
  reader = csv.reader(f_obj)
  providerlist = list(reader)

providerlist = [[k.lower()] for l in providerlist for k in l]
x = x.split()
res = [ele for ele in x if(ele in providerlist)]
print("Does string contain any list element : " + str(bool(res)))
```

Comment: Qual o resultado que está saindo?

Comment: Sempre me retorna False. Mesmo minha input tendo uma única palavra que está presente no fornecedores.csv

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que estava criando uma lista de listas.
Como por exemplo: [['fornecedor1'],['fornecedor2']]
A solução foi a seguinte:

```
c = len (providerlist)

for i in range(c):
  providerlist += providerlist[i]
```

Agora a lista fica: ['fornecedor1','fornecedor2']
Solucionando o problema.